# Testng data provider Getting error "Data provider mismatch"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

Here I am assigning data

```
public static Object[][][] SiteUrlForSignin = {
    {{"https://google.com"},{"username"},{"mypassword"}}
};
```

Here is my test class

```
public class SignInTest{

    @DataProvider(name = "SigninLink")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        Object[][][] data = SiteConfig.SiteUrlForSignin;
        return data;
    }    

    @Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true, dataProvider = "SigninLink")
    public void mytest(String url,String username,String password,Method method,ITestContext ctx) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        System.out.println(url+"-"+username+"-"+password);
    }
}
```

Getting following error

> has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider
> (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level
> annotation). Data provider mismatch

I am not sure where I missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in the code.

1. Your single test case expects url, username and password. So it should be a single array `{"https://google.com","username","mypassword"}`
2. Also data provider expected 2-d array, but your `SiteUrlForSignin` is a 3-d array. Convert it as:

```
public static Object[][] SiteUrlForSignin = {{"https://google.com","username","mypassword"}};
```

**Note:** According to the documentation, you cannot inject `Method` into a method annotated with `@Test`. It is applicable only to `@BeforeMethod`, `@AfterMethod` and `@DataProvider`, But it is possible now :-)

Not sure if it is a bug or if the documentation is not updated.

Comment: @ZakariaShahed that was a mistake. updated

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the issue. The below error...

```
  Data provider mismatch
  Method: mytest([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, 
    declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String,   
    declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, 
    declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, ype=java.lang.reflect.Method, 
    declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=4, type=org.testng.ITestContext, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
    
  Arguments: 
   [([Ljava.lang.Object;) [https://google.com],
   ([Ljava.lang.Object;) [username],
   ([Ljava.lang.Object;) [mypassword]]
```

...is saying "The method requires `{String, String, String}` input but you are passing `{Object, Object, Object}`

**Working code**:

```
@Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true, dataProvider = "SigninLink")
public void mytest(Object url, Object username, Object password, Method method, ITestContext ctx)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    System.out.println(Array.get(url, 0) + "-" + Array.get(username, 0) + "-" + Array.get(password, 0));
}
```

**Output**:

```
https://google.com-username-mypassword
```

Instead of that simply you can pass the data like below.

```
@DataProvider(name = "SigninLink")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][] { { "https://google.com", "username", "mypassword" } };
    }

@Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true, dataProvider = "SigninLink")
public void mytest(String url, String username, String password, Method method, ITestContext ctx)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    System.out.println(url + "-" + username + "-" + password);
}
```